# Show that $\mathcal{B}_{A}=\left\{ B\cap A\mid B\in\mathcal{B}\right\}$ is a base for the subspace topology of $A$.

Tags: general-topology

Trying to improve my understanding topology definitions, any feed back on the following would be great. I don't have anyone to bounce ideas with this summer, so I hope someone out there can help.

Suppose that $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for the topology of $X$ and $A\subseteq X$. Show that $\mathcal{B}_{A}=\left\{ B\cap A\mid B\in\mathcal{B}\right\}$  is a base for the subspace topology of $A$.

Proof.

By defintion of base, we want to show that $\mathcal{B}_{A}\subseteq\tau_{A}$ where $\tau_{A}=\left\{ V\cap A\mid A\in\tau\right\}$  and whenever $x\in W\in\tau_{A}$ there exists a $B'\in\mathcal{B}_{A}$ such that $x\in B'\subseteq W$.

First, we show $\mathcal{B}_{A}\subseteq\tau_{A}$. Let $V\in\mathcal{B}_{A}$. Then $V=B\cap A$ for $B\in\mathcal{B}$. Since $A\in\tau_{A}$ and $B\cap A\subseteq A$ we have $V\in\tau_{A}$.

Lastly, let $x\in W\in\tau_{A}$. Then $W=V\cap A$ for $V\in\tau$. Let $x\in V\cap A\in\tau$. Then there is a $B\in\mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq V\cap A$, which means $B\subseteq V$ and $B\subseteq A$. Let $B'=B\cap A$. Then there is a $B'\in \mathcal{B}_{A}$ such that $x\in B'\subseteq V\cap A=W$.

Therefore, $\mathcal{B}_{A}$ is a base for $\tau_{A}$.

Comment: Note: A subbase is something different. It's a family of open sets whose finite intersections form a base of the topology.

Comment: You write $\tau_A = \{ V \cap A \mid A \in \tau\}$, but it ought to be $\tau_A = \{ V \cap A \mid V \in \tau\}$.

Comment: Thank you, other than that what else should I pay close attention too.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument that $\mathcal{B}_A \subseteq \tau_A$ isn't correct. $A \in \tau_A$ and $B \cap A \subseteq A$ holds for all $B$, regardless of whether $B \in \mathcal{B}_A$ or not. The fact that you have to use<sup>(1)</sup> is that $\mathcal{B} \subset \tau$.

The other argument isn't correct either, you say "Let $x\in V\cap A \in \tau$. Then there is a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subseteq V\cap A$, which means $B \subseteq V$ and $B\subseteq A$." But if for example $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $A = \{0\}$, then no nonempty open set is contained in $V \cap A$ for any open $V$.

You need to go from the existence of $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B \subset V$ to $x \in B \cap A \subset V \cap A$.

<sup>(1)</sup> There may be ways to avoid that, but I don't quickly see one.

Comment: Thanks, I still have no idea what to do then, I have been told the proof for this 3 times today, I still can't reproduce it, and I still don't understand it.  Very frustrating.

Comment: You need to show that $\mathcal{B}_A \subset \tau_A$, that means for every $B \in \mathcal{B}$, there is a $V \in \tau$ such that $B \cap A = V \cap A$. Now, $\mathcal{B} \subset \tau$, hence we can simply choose $V = B$. Then you must show that each $V\cap A$ is the union of a family $B_\iota\cap A$, or equivalently, that for each $x \in V\cap A$ there is a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x \in B\cap A$ and $B\cap A \subset V\cap A$. For the union, $\mathcal{B}$ is a base, hence $V = \bigcup_{\iota\in I} B_\iota$, therefore $V\cap A = \bigcup_{\iota\in I} (B_\iota\cap A)$. For the other method

Comment: Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a base of $\tau$, there exists a $B \in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B \subset V$. But then, since $x \in A$, you have $x \in B\cap A \subset V\cap A$. Did the fourth time help a little?

Comment: So, $\mathcal{B}_A\subseteq \tau_A$ since for every $B\in \mathcal{B}$ there is a $V\in \tau$ such that $B\cap A=V\cap A$.

Comment: Right. Namely $B$.

Comment: Now, want to show that $\forall x\in W\in \tau_A$ there exists a $B'\in \mathcal{B}_A$ such that $x\in B'\in W$. This is what I interpret.

Comment: $\forall x\in A\in \tau$ and $\forall x\in V\in \tau$ $\exists B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq V$ $\implies$ $\forall x\in V\cap A\in \tau\exists B\cap A\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\cap A\subseteq V\cap A$ which implies conclusion.

Comment: @user60675 The last one went wrong. Too many quantifiers, for one. You start with one $W \in \tau_A$. That is fixed. Then you select an arbitrary $x \in W$. You can do that by wrapping all that follows in one giant $\bigl(\forall x \in W\bigr)$, but if you say it in words, "let $x \in W$ arbitrary", it probably leads to something more readable. Then you have two fixed items, $W$ and $x$. Then you need one $\exists$, namely $\bigl(\exists B \in \mathcal{B}\bigr)(x \in B\cap A \land B\cap A \subset W)$. To get that, you need to choose a $V \in \tau$ with $W = V\cap A$ (okay, another $\exists$).

Comment: Let $x\in W\in \tau_A$ be arbitrary, that is, there is a $V\in \tau$ such that $x\in V\cap A\in \tau$. Then there is a $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\cap A$ and $B\cap A\subseteq V\cap A$, that is, there is a $B'\in \mathcal{B}_A$ such that $x\in B'$ and $B'\subseteq W$.

Comment: Close. First, you wrote $x \in V\cap A \in \tau$, but $V\cap A$ is in general not open in $X$. All you need of that is $W = V\cap A$. Then, for the $B \in \mathcal{B}$, you first have $x \in B \subset V$ ("since $\mathcal{B}$ is a base, there is a ..."). From that follows (very directly) that $x \in B\cap A \subset V\cap A = W$.

Comment: since $\mathcal{B}$ is a base, there is a $B'\in \mathcal{B}_A=\{B\cap A|B\in \mathcal{B}\}$.

Comment: No, "since $\mathcal{B}$ is a base (of $\tau$), there is a $B\in \mathcal{B}$ with $x \in B \subset V$". Then, intersecting with $A$ yields $x \in B\cap A \subset V\cap A = W$, and by definition of $\mathcal{B}_A$, you have $B \cap A \in \mathcal{B}_A$.

Comment: Let $x\in W\in \tau_A$, i.e. there is a $V\in \tau$ such that $x\in V\cap A=W$. Since $\mathcal{B}$ is a base of $\tau$, there is a $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq V$. Then after intersecting with $A$ we have $x\in B\cap A\subseteq V\cap A=W$. Thus, by definition we have $B\cap A\in \mathcal{B}_A$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience I feel like I did with my first $\epsilon$ - $\delta$ proof.

Comment: Ah, the first steps are always a bit wobbly. It gets better with some practice.

Answer (score 1):

Let's just work from the definition.  A base $\mathcal{B}$ of a topological space $X$ is a collection of open sets such that every open set can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

So let $U \subset A$ be an open set in $A$.  Then $U = W \cap A$ where $W \subset X$ is open.  By assumption, there are elements $B_i \in \mathcal{B}$ such that $\bigcup B_i = W$, and so

$$U = \bigg(\bigcup B_i\bigg) \cap A  = \bigcup (B_i \cap A)$$

This proves that $\mathcal{B}_A = \{B \cap A : B \in \mathcal{B}\}$ is a basis for $A$.